I installed distro 24.04 and now I have no sound
Was running 20.04 and ran fine. Sound good. Did an upgrade and had no sound. Decided to do a full install and the same thing. No sound. I am not a linux wizard and all I see for a fix is mumbo jumbo. I tried a few things and nothing is working. Kind of strange that a new distribution would have a problem like this. Seems many people are having the same thing. Any real fixes out there?? By the way, I have a dual boot with windows and audio is good there....
lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Dell Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 42, IOMMU group 2
    Memory at f7c34000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
--
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 41, IOMMU group 7
    Memory at f7c30000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])


Please run lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio" and Edit your question to include this information.

You have 2 different hardware audio devices on your system (Exclusive of Bluetooth and HDMI devices). You can select the correct audio output device you want in your sound "Settings". This can be found by either clicking on the speaker icon in the top right corner of your screen or by pressing the "Super key" button on your keyboard then type "settings" in the search box.
The settings dialog box will give you options similar to this:


I have tried changing the settings. Before it worked well on the HDMI setting since I have a HDMI plugged into my monitor.

@TonyM Is it working now?
